# Using Function to generate numbers

Tags: python, function

```
def generate(num):
    res = 0
    for i in str(num):
       res = res + int(i)
    return res + num
```

I was looking at someone's code for generating numbers and I don't understand why he used 'str(num)' to iterate i to num. Then he translates the str(i) again to int(i).

What is the intention behind this? Why can we not create

```
def generate(num):
    res = 0
    for i in num:
       res = res + i
    return res + num
```

from the beginning?

Thanks

Comment: `for i in num:` will raise an error, saying that an `int` (or a `float`, depending on the argument you passed) is not iterable. Strings are, on the other hand, iterables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By turning a number into a string, you are allowed to iterate over the various digits.

Try this:

```
for c in str(123):
   print(c)
```

Of course, `c` is then a string, so if you want to use the digit as a number, you need to cast it back to an `int`.

In other words, the first function you shared computes the sum of the digits of a number. The second function you shared would compute the sum of numbers in an iterable, like a list of integers.

A single `int` is not an iterable, while a single `str` is - so `for x in y:` will work if `y` is a `str`, but it will cause an error if `y` is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet,

```
def generate(num):
    res = 0
    for i in str(num):
       res = res + int(i)
    return res + num
```

assumes num is a `numerical` value and adds the individual digits of a given number to produce `res` and then it adds that `res` to the the number itself,
So, when you call `generate(123)` it adds `(1 + 2 + 3) + 123` which produces `129`

---

The second code snippet raises and error when `num` is a numerical value.

Hope it helps!